# How to create class instances dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a collection of classes (Around 100) (Assume Class1, Class2, Class3). I want to create lists dynamically and add to a list. For example `List<abc> test1 = new List<abc>();` abc could be Class1/Class2/ClassN.How to do it?

Comment: @FeistyMango they are entirely unrelated classes, already defined in my code, depend on the condition I want to create the list

Comment: What condition decides the objects you want to load at runtime? I ask because it's easy enough to show you how to load objects using reflection at runtime ... I wonder if there is a better design approach I can recommend based on what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: @FeistyMango Exactly. Actually it is for a Ms Access database. I am going to check whether a table exist in that database. If the table exist, I am going to create a list with respective table class and add the objects to that list

Comment: Do the classes inherit from a common base class or interface

Comment: @Jetti, they are unrelated

Comment: @Rambo See the answer I posted, I had to make a few edits after double checking my work in VS.

Comment: @FeistyMango. It is great. That should be one way, but Is there any other ways? What do you think about Initializing all the lists and keep it in a ArrayList, then use it

Comment: @Rambo You are attempting to hit the db and see what tables exist and then instantiate entity objects at runtime ... there really isn't any other magical recipe for something like that unless you want to build a factory pattern for every object in your database ... gross!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, using reflection this can be done in a pretty straightforward fashion.

```
public List<object> LoadObjectsFromAssembly(Assembly assemblyContainingClasses)
{
     var objectList = new List<object>();
     List<Type> classNames = assemblyContainingClasses.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract).ToList();

     foreach(var classType in classNames) 
     {
         Type typeToLoad = assemblyContainingClasses.GetType(classType.FullName);
         objectList.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(typeToLoad));
     }
     return objectList;
}
```